# Parse a zip object using ast.literal_eval() or eval()

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, jinja2

I have a zip object available in the Jinja template page, and when a user clicks some link I am sending that zip object as a request parameter. And then I try to parse the zip object using ast.literal_eval() but I am getting "Invalid syntax" error.

I tried using eval() as literal_eval(). But both are giving me the same error. I searched for it but haven't found anything which describes how to parse a "" notation.

**views.py**

```py
data = request.GET
movies,moviesindxs = zip(*literal_eval(data.get("movies")))
```

**jinja template**

```
{% for movie,movieindx in movies %}
   <a href="{% url 'rate_movie'  %}?&movies={{movies}}&movie={{movie}}&movieindx={{movieindx}}" method="GET">Random Text</a>
{% endfor %}
```

```sh
File "~/path/to/Django/app/views.py", line 198, in rate_movie
    movies, moviesindxs = zip(*literal_eval(data.get("movies")))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 48, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    <zip object at 0x12d6549c8>
```

Comment: If you're getting this from a request think twice, a malicious user can execute arbitrary code just by encoding it on the url

Comment: Anyway, zip will return a iterator, not a string, you need a string to call eval, here is an example `eval(repr(list(zip(range(10), range(10, 20)))))` but really, don't call eval on stuff coming from the request

Comment: data.get('movies') gives me a string. Also just evaluating a literal using literal_eval() would be safe, right?

Comment: Almost: From the documentation: _Warning It is possible to crash the Python interpreter with a sufficiently large/complex string due to stack depth limitations in Python’s AST compiler._

Comment: Using json is the way to go. Print the contents of `request.GET['movies']` so we can reproduce

Comment: `print(request.GET['movies'])` -> `<zip object at 0x12d6549c8>`

Comment: The string representation of a `zip` object is not going to work with either `eval` or `ast.literal_eval` (it's definitely not a literal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the change of implementation of `zip()` function. As [`zip()` in Python2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) used to return list of tuples, which would've worked with `ast.literal_eval()`. But in [Python3.x `zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#zip) function returns a lazy iterator, which can't be parsed using either `ast.literal_eval` or 'eval()'. So, for that reason now I'm sending `list(zip())` from **views.py** to the Jinja template. Which can be sent back to `views` in request parameters as a `list` literal.